# Nothing happens on clicking Edit Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a Grid control in asp .NET with Edit button. When I click the edit button I expect the form to be filled with the value of fields of row on which edit button was clicked, but nothing happens.

Here is the code

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Reg_form_new.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyFirstProject.Reg_form_new" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .form {
           max-width: 470px;

            margin: 20px auto;
            border:1px solid silver;
            padding:40px;
            border-top:5px solid #D2BE24;
        }
     
        #Button1 {
            background-color: #D2BE24;
            color:white;
            font-weight:bold;
        }

        .fas {
            border: 1px solid #cfd5da;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .form-group {
            margin: 20px 0;
        }

        .form-control {
            border-radius: 0px;
        }

        #rdbmale {
            position: relative;
            left: 11px;
        }

        #rdbfemale {
            position: relative;
            right: 61px;
        }
        .heading{
            text-align:center;
            font-weight:bold;
            font-size:25px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="form">
            <div class="heading">
                Responsive Registeration form
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></div>
                    <div class="col-md-11">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" placeholder="Email" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Email is required" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid email" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></div>
                    <div class="col-md-11">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text="Password" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Password is required" ControlToValidate="TextBox2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></div>
                    <div class="col-md-11">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text="Re-type Password" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Re-type Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required" ControlToValidate="TextBox3"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Password and Re-type password must match" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ControlToCompare="TextBox2" Operator="Equal" Type="String" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic"></asp:CompareValidator>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row ">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="row ">
                            <div class="col-md-2"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" placeholder="First Name" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" ErrorMessage="First name is required" ControlToValidate="TextBox4"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" placeholder="Last Name" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Last name is required" ControlToValidate="TextBox5"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1" ID="rdbmale">Male</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2" ID="rdbfemale">Female</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvGender" runat="server"
                        ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList1"
                        InitialValue=""
                        ErrorMessage="Please select your gender."
                        Display="Dynamic"
                        CssClass="error"
                         ForeColor="Red">
                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" Display="Dynamic" InitialValue="0" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Subject is required" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="I agree with the terms and conditions"  CssClass="AcceptedAgreement"/>
                <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CheckBoxRequired" EnableClientScript="true"
    OnServerValidate="CheckBoxRequired_ServerValidate"
    ClientValidationFunction="CheckBoxRequired_ClientValidate" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic">You must select this box to proceed.</asp:CustomValidator>
                   <br />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Text=" I want to receive the newsletter" />
            </div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Register" CssClass="form-control" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="false"   OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"  CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" HeaderStyle-CssClass="table-dark" RowStyle-CssClass="table-light table-hover">
            <Columns>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Button runat="server"    OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" Text="Edit"  ID="Button1"   OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"  CommandName ="Edittt" CausesValidation="false"  />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="delete" CausesValidation="false"  />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubject" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        function CheckBoxRequired_ClientValidate(sender, e) {
            e.IsValid = jQuery(".AcceptedAgreement input:checkbox").is(':checked');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MyFirstProject
{
    public partial class Reg_form_new : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            // Code to handle the event
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
        }

        protected void MyGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Edittt")
            {
                // Get the index of the row in which the Edit button was clicked
                int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

                // Find the row using the index and get the values of the fields
                GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
                string email = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
                string password = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox2")).Text;
                string firstName = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox4")).Text;
                string lastName = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox5")).Text;
                string gender = ((RadioButtonList)row.FindControl("RadioButtonList1")).SelectedValue;
                string subject = ((DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownList1")).SelectedValue;
                bool acceptedAgreement = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1")).Checked;

                Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");

                // Do something with the retrieved values
                // ...
                TextBox1.Text = row.Cells[5].Text;
                TextBox2.Text = password;
                TextBox3.Text = firstName;
                TextBox4.Text = lastName;
                TextBox5.Text = gender;
                DropDownList1.SelectedValue = subject;
            }
        }
       
        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                DropDownList ddlSubject = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlSubject");
                ddlSubject.DataSource = GetSubjects(); // replace GetSubjects() with your own method to get the list of subjects
                ddlSubject.DataBind();

                // set the selected subject by default
                string selectedSubject = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["Subject"].ToString();
                ddlSubject.SelectedValue = selectedSubject;

                Button btnEdit = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("Button1"); // Replace "Button1" with the ID of your Edit button control
                btnEdit.CommandArgument = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
            }
        }
       
        private List<string> GetSubjects()
        {
            // replace this method with your own method to get the list of subjects
            return new List<string> { "Math", "Science", "English", "History" };
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                // create dropdown items
                ListItem item0 = new ListItem("Select a subject", "0");
                ListItem item1 = new ListItem("English", "1");
                ListItem item2 = new ListItem("Math", "2");
                ListItem item3 = new ListItem("Science", "3");

                // add items to dropdown list
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(item0);
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(item1);
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(item2);
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(item3);
            }
        }

        protected void CheckBoxRequired_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
        {
            e.IsValid = CheckBox1.Checked;
        }

        public void createnewrow()
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable datatbl = new DataTable();
                if (ViewState["Row"] != null)
                {
                    datatbl = (DataTable)ViewState["Row"];
                }

                // Define the necessary columns if they haven't been defined yet
                if (datatbl.Columns.Count == 0)
                {
                    datatbl.Columns.Add("email", typeof(string));
                    datatbl.Columns.Add("password", typeof(string));
                    datatbl.Columns.Add("firstname", typeof(string));
                    datatbl.Columns.Add("lastname", typeof(string));
                    datatbl.Columns.Add("gender", typeof(string));
                    datatbl.Columns.Add("subject", typeof(string));
                }

                // Create a new DataRow object and add it to the DataTable
                DataRow dr = datatbl.NewRow();
                dr["email"] = TextBox1.Text;
                dr["password"] = TextBox2.Text;
                dr["firstname"] = TextBox4.Text;
                dr["lastname"] = TextBox5.Text;
                dr["gender"] = RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text;
                dr["subject"] = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
                datatbl.Rows.Add(dr);

                ViewState["Row"] = datatbl;
                GridView1.DataSource = ViewState["Row"];
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle exceptions as appropriate
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsValid && CheckBox1.Checked)
            {
                createnewrow();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the `onRowCommand` I have written code to populate form. The problem is related to an ASP.NET web page that contains a grid control with an Edit button. When the user clicks the Edit button, the form is expected to be filled with the values of the fields of the row on which the Edit button was clicked. However, nothing happens when the Edit button is clicked. The code for the web page is provided, and it includes the HTML and CSS styles used for the form.